# Output heap as tree PHP

Tags: php, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-heap

I have an array `$heap = array(9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 7, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9,);` and I want to output It like binary tree, when the two children nodes we can know by this formulas, `$heap[$key*2+1]` and second `$heap[$key*2+2]`. I try to run using foreach but getting error about undefined offset 21. Here is foreach:

```
foreach ($heap as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
    if ($key != count($heap)) {
        echo $heap[$key*2+1];
        echo $heap[$key*2+2];
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong and how I can solve this?

Comment: Bro its notice not an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error in your check:

```
if ($key != count($heap)) {
    echo $heap[$key*2+1];
    echo $heap[$key*2+2];
}
```

Here may be a situation with `$key*2+2` is out of bounds the array. Add the check for it too. Try to use 
`bool array_key_exists ( mixed $key , array $array )`, something like this:

```
if ($key != count($heap)) {
    if (array_key_exists($key*2 + 1, $heap)) echo $heap[$key*2 + 1];
    if (array_key_exists($key*2 + 2, $heap) ) echo $heap[$key*2 + 2];
}
```

As you point out in comment, you are doubling the values in your code. This can be avoided by recursive function, something like this (pseudocode):

```
printArray(i, aHeap) {
    if (i < count($heap)) {
        echo $heap[i];
        printArray(2*i + 1, aHeap);
        printArray(2*i + 2, aHeap);
    }
}
```

Comment: no no now it works. strange why this not work earlier. its check for the situation when elements in heap will be come to disspear

Comment: i want to output each node a single time, but for now I get the each node repeat by two times, ance as children node and the second with it own children nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a notice to stop it just define the offset by just checking if array key exists. Use the code below

```
foreach ($heap as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
    if ($key != count($heap)) {
         if (array_key_exists($key*2 + 1, $heap)){ echo $heap[$key*2 + 1];}
    if (array_key_exists($key*2 + 2, $heap) ){ echo $heap[$key*2 + 2]; }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could do this without checking if key exists with a for:

```
for($i = 0, $m = count($heap) - 1; $i < $m - 2; $i++) {
    echo $heap[$i+1];
    echo $heap[$i+2];
}
```

This will assure that the key only goes to all indexes - 2, so in the last iteration $i + 2 will be the last key.